# what is the best practice to inject variables into a java class method

Tags: java

i want to dynamic run some java source code which post from remoting.
now, my solution:

1. compile the source code with `JavaCompiler`
2. load the class with `URLClassLoader`
3. invoke the target ***method*** (which is my pre-defined interface)

the following is my sample code.

```java
package com.pkg;

// Pre-defined interface
public interface Executor {
    void execute(Map<String, ?> someArgPairs);
}
```

```java
// source code received from remoting

// imports block
import com.pkg.Executor;
import ...;

public class WhateverExecutor implements Executor {
    @Override
    public void execute(Map<String, ?> someArgPairs) {
        // do something with <someArgParis>
    }

}
```

```java
// imports block
import ...;

// main
public class SampleEntry {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // 0. define map argument - the interface method need
        var someArgPairs = new HashMap<>();

        // 1. compile - compile the code, and generate a local .class file
        JavaCompiler compiler = ...;
        
        // 2. load - load the class from the local .class file
        URLClassLoader loader = ...;
        Class<?> clazz = loader.load(className); // assume the class name correct.

        // 3. call - invoke the interface's method
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("execute", Map.class);
        method.invoke(clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(), someArgPairs);
        
        // more ...
    }
}
```

you see, i need define the interface `Executor` firstly, then force remote guys implements it.

now, i wanna know that, is there some tech that can allow me to inject a variable into the method.
with this, the remote guy and i just reach an agreement that within the context of execution, he/she can use pre-named variables.

like:

```java
// source code from remote
public class FreedomClassName {
    public void freedomMethod() {
        System.out.println(namedVar);  // namedVar will be injected 
    }
}
```

with code above, i just need invoke the specified method with reflection, he/she be free.

Any one can help?

**the best practice to inject a `named variable` into method without parameter declaration** (like lombok generate a `log` for the annotated class)

Answer (score 0):

You already have a contract established with the other party in the interface:

```java
    void execute(Map<String, ?> someArgPairs);
```

`someArgPairs` is actually a map of variable names to values. Instead of magically injected variables use that map.

Comment: well, iI'm trying not to create this hierarchical relationship. Just let clients use the symbols of context